# Executing e2e tests via API on server and serverless environment

Tags: python, server, serverless, playwright, e2e

I've recently implemented a system where I execute end-to-end written on [playwright](https://playwright.dev/) tests through an API call on my server. The process involves triggering a Python script that performs browser-based tests using Playwright. Everything seems to be working well in my local environment.

The test script is fairly simple, I've a FLASK webserver that initiates `subprocess` to call another python file which holds e2e test

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pytest
import subprocess
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/execute-hook', methods=['POST'])
def run_test():
    url = request.json.get('url')  # Assuming the JSON payload contains the URL

    result = subprocess.run(['python3', 'auto_confirm_appointment.py', url, '--browser chrome'], capture_output=True, text=True)

    message = "The time slot is no longer available" if result.returncode == 0 else "The appointment is scheduled"

    return jsonify({"message": message, "success": result.returncode == 1 })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

auto_confirm_appointment.py

```
# Not putting whole code as it is unrelated. just for the sake of question, the code contain
and external link and perform various browser related operation
```

I'm considering deploying this solution in a server or serverless environment. However, I'm unsure whether this approach is the right one. Are there any potential issues or challenges I should be aware of when running end-to-end tests in a serverless/server environment? Also As the traffic increases, the number of API calls and tests will also rise. How can I effectively manage this scalability challenge

Your insights and experiences would be greatly appreciated!